# How to manually map colours to treemap?

Tags: r, treemap

I am using `treemap` from the `treemap` package to create a visual representation.

Simply put, I create a `treemap` from a table of values and depending on the values I map red, grey and green colours to the sections of the `treemap`.

Under certain circumstance this works but under others it does not and I get an error I can't figure out:

`Error in do.call("format", args.legend) : second argument must be a list`

So far it seems that whilst setting `type = "value"` if all boxes in a parent group have size `0` and you are trying to specify colours, then the error occurs. If however, you have two boxes in a parent group and you set one to zero, it will still work as long as both the colour specifications in those groups are not the same.

I will try and outline this below.

This works: with a red, grey and green box appearing according to whether they were assigned `-1, 0` or `1` in the `Colour` column.

```
# This is just c(red, grey, green)
my_colour_pal <- c("#bc0303", "#4b5566", "#17a008")
df <- 
  data.frame(Group1 = c("one", "one", "two"),
             Group2 = c("val1", "val2", "val3"),
             Value = c(10, 10, 10),
             Colour = c(-1, 0, 1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

treemap(df, index = c("Group1", "Group2"), type = "value",
        vSize = "Value", vColor = "Colour", palette = my_colour_pal)
```

This also work: in the same way, except one box is gone because `Value` is equal to `0`. As expected the colour mapping works.

```
df <- 
  data.frame(Group1 = c("one", "one", "two"),
             Group2 = c("val1", "val2", "val3"),
             Value = c(10, 0, 10),
             Colour = c(-1, 0, 1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

treemap(df, index = c("Group1", "Group2"), type = "value",
        vSize = "Value", vColor = "Colour", palette = my_colour_pal)
```

This doesn't work: Both `Group1` assignments for `one` have `Value` set to zero

```
df <- 
  data.frame(Group1 = c("one", "one", "two"),
             Group2 = c("val1", "val2", "val3"),
             Value = c(0, 0, 10),
             Colour = c(-1, 0, 1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

treemap(df, index = c("Group1", "Group2"), type = "value",
        vSize = "Value", vColor = "Colour", palette = my_colour_pal)

Error in do.call("format", args.legend) : second argument must be a list
```

However, if I do the same and set the third Value to `0` then it works fine

```
my_colour_pal <- c("#bc0303", "#4b5566", "#17a008")
df <- 
  data.frame(Group1 = c("one", "one", "two"),
             Group2 = c("val1", "val2", "val3"),
             Value = c(10, 10, 0),
             Colour = c(-1, 0, 1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

treemap(df, index = c("Group1", "Group2"), type = "value",
        vSize = "Value", vColor = "Colour", palette = my_colour_pal)
```

Finally, if I do the same as last time but set both the colours of row 1 and 2 to be the same eg. `-1` for "red" then I get the same error,

```
df <- 
  data.frame(Group1 = c("one", "one", "two"),
             Group2 = c("val1", "val2", "val3"),
             Value = c(10, 10, 0),
             Colour = c(-1, -1, 1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

treemap(df, index = c("Group1", "Group2"), type = "value",
        vSize = "Value", vColor = "Colour", palette = my_colour_pal)

Error in do.call("format", args.legend) : second argument must be a list
```

## In Summary

It seems like the error occurs if Both boxes in a parent group are equal to zero and if both the boxes in the parent group have the Colour value set to the same number.

Comment: I think `type = "manual"` is the appropriate parameter for mapping to a user-defined palette. See `?treemap`.

Comment: @neilfws Even with `type = "manual"` I receive the error.

Comment: I think the basic issue here is just that it isn't sensible for the top-level group to have a value of zero.

Comment: Would that not mean that my third example should also give an error? @neilfws